# Cryptographic failure in WPF Reports v0.4 alpha

Tags: wpf

I just downloaded the [WPF Reports v0.4 alpha](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30775)

When I build the project in VS 2008 I got the following error.

```
Cryptographic failure while signing assembly ' \CodeReason.Reports\obj\Debug
   \CodeReason.Reports.dll' -- 'Access is denied. ' CodeReason.Reports.VS2008
```

What is this error mean and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen on Vista/Windows 7 when your account does not have permissions to he MachineKeys directory.

Just grant your user full control to folder `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

Original source: http://blog.devstone.com/aaron/2005/12/01/AccessDeniedWhileSigningAssembly.aspx

Comment: The path for me on Vista was %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys.